# Screen resolution detection in Windows 8 Apps

Tags: c#, windows, silverlight, xaml

Is there a way I can detect the resolution of the screen in a Windows 8 app so that I can scale and resize the elements of the UI accordingly?

If not then what is the best way to go about developing an app that is resolution independent? Is there a standard way that I am not aware of or is there some other way this can be achieved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anything these two articles don't explain?

[Guidelines for scaling to screens (Windows Store apps)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh780612.aspx)

[Building Windows 8 : Scaling to different screens](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/b8/archive/2012/03/21/scaling-to-different-screens.aspx)

Comment: The first link did help me. I am now designing for a base resolution of 1366x768 putting all of my UI into a Viewbox control. It's working pretty well up till now.

Answer (score 3):

Anything that inherits from FrameworkElement has a SizeChanged event.  This event returns the current size of the framework element.

To get the overall size of the screen you can use:

```
Windows.UI.Xaml.Window.Current.Bounds.Height
Windows.UI.Xaml.Window.Current.Bounds.Width
```

Be careful as this will return the size of the screen and you will need to take into account whether your app is full-screen or Snapped/Filled.

Microsoft guidance says that you should be avoiding absolute values for height/width and simply setting HorizontalAlignment and VerticalAlignment to Stretch to allow the UI to take as much space as it needs to render.

Comment: I did figure it out. I am now designing for a base resolution of 1366x768 putting all of my UI into a Viewbox control. It's working pretty well up till now.

Comment: It gives current size of the app windows not the system, if may produce false results when screen is in snapped view

Comment: By default Windows store apps design for the screen which has screen size 10.6" and resolution 1366*768.If I want to design my app for every screen size and every resolution?Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

```
Windows.Graphics.Display.DisplayProperties.LogicalDpi
```

Comment: I'm going to upvote this cryptic answer, because this helped my issue, unlike every other answer.  I was looking to get device screen resolution from logical WinRT pixel dimensions.  Logical pixel width x (logical dpi / 96) gives me device pixel width.

Comment: Why did you divided to 96?