# Windows 8.1 Application Screen size in inches

Tags: windows-8.1, screen, info

I am developing Windows 8.1 Application, currently I am, struggling with getting the actual screen size in inches or any other measurement unit.

Is it possible to get that information?

Answer (score 0):

```
var bounds = Window.Current.Bounds;
    double w = bounds.Width;
    double h = bounds.Height;
    switch (DisplayProperties.ResolutionScale)
    {
       case ResolutionScale.Scale140Percent:
            w = Math.Ceiling(w * 1.4);
            h = Math.Ceiling(h * 1.4);
            break;
        case ResolutionScale.Scale180Percent:
            w = Math.Ceiling(w * 1.8);
            h = Math.Ceiling(h * 1.8);
            break;
    }

    Size resolution = new Size(w, h);
```

Answer taken from here: [link](http://programmerpayback.com/2013/08/31/detecting-screen-resolution-in-windows-8-and-windows-phone-apps/)
and here: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12907435/screen-resolution-detection-in-windows-8-apps/19660667#19660667)

Comment: This code gives me a resolution, what I want is the size of the screen in inches. I ran this code in blank app and also get wrong resolution - I think it's cause it's based on Window.Current.Bounds  - which is the dimensions of my current windows application, and not my screen dimensions.

Comment: You can get the DPI like this:

Windows.Graphics.Display.DisplayProperties.LogicalDpi

and then calculate the size:
pixles / DPI = Inches